# Export query to relational xml

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssms

In management studio is it possible to create a relational XML file?

example:

```
select a.product, a.cost, b.productType, c.brand
from products a 
inner join productTypes b on a.productTypeID = b.productTypeID
inner join brands c on b.brandID = c.brandID
```

to create XML File

```
<brands>
   <brand>SomeBrand1
       <productType>SomeProductType
           <product>Product1</product>
           <Cost>$10.00</cost>   
        </productType>
   <brand>    
   <brand>SomeBrand2
       <productType>SomeProductType
           <product>Product3</product>
           <Cost>$10.00</cost>   
           <product>Product4</product>
           <Cost>$10.00</cost>   
        </productType>
   <brand>
</brands>
```

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: There is The FOR XML Clause you can use to create xml from relational data [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx). I would suggest to read the FOR XML PATH part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nesting to generate the XML in the shape you want.  This code creates the tables that I used.

```
--create products
select 'product1' product, 10.00 cost, 1 productTypeID into #Products
insert into #Products select 'product3', 10.00 cost, 2 productTypeID
insert into #Products select 'product4', 10.00 cost, 2 productTypeID

--create product types
select 1 productTypeID, 'SomeProductType1' productType, 1 brandID into #productTypes
insert into #productTypes select 2 productTypeID, 'SomeProductType2' productType, 2 brandID

--brands
select 1 brandID, 'SomeBrand1' brand into #brands
insert into #brands select 2 brandID, 'SomeBrand2' brand
```

I could be wrong, but I made an assumption that you needed two distinct product types so I created two of them.  The way your join query was structured, it has a one to many relationship from brand to product type.  This would imply that each product type belongs to only one brand.  I suppose both brand type records could have the same name, and this would result in the XML you cited in your question.

The following statement should then create the shape of XML in your example:

```
select ltrim(brand),
    (select LTRIM(productType),
        (select product, cost
        from #Products
        where #Products.productTypeID = #productTypes.productTypeID
        order by product
        for XML PATH(''), type
        )
    from #productTypes
    where #productTypes.brandID = #brands.brandID
    order by productType
    for XML path('productType'), type
    )
from #brands
order by brand
for xml path('brand'), root('brands')
```

The output:

```
<brands>
  <brand>SomeBrand1
    <productType>SomeProductType1
      <product>product1</product>
      <cost>10.00</cost>
    </productType>
  </brand>
  <brand>SomeBrand2
    <productType>SomeProductType2
      <product>product3</product>
      <cost>10.00</cost>
      <product>product4</product>
      <cost>10.00</cost>
    </productType>
  </brand>
</brands>
```

The outermost XML path statement "for xml path('brand'), root('brands')" wraps the entire XML in a root called "brands" and then creates elements called "brand" for each row returned.  After the select, I wrapped the brand column in an ltrim function without an alias so that it would not return a column name, which inserts the text inline without creating a tag for it in the XML.

The next column selected is a sub-query that returns the XML snip for the product types.  The "Type" keyword follows the XML path of this sub-query to indicate that it is to be interpreted as XML.

The innermost sub-query just returns the product and cost for all records belonging to the product type.  By specifying "for XML PATH('')" indicates that it should not create a "row" tag for each row.

Answer (score 1):

it's not absolutely the same by structure, but result is the same:

```
select a.product, a.cost, b.productType, c.brand
from products a 
inner join productTypes b on a.productTypeID = b.productTypeID
inner join brands c on b.brandID = c.brandID
FOR XML PATH ('brand'), TYPE, ROOT ('brands')
```

OUTPUT

```
<brands>
  <brand>
    <brand>SomeBrand1</brand>
    <product>Product1</product>
    <cost>10.00</cost>
    <productType>SomeProductType</productType>
  </brand>
  <brand>
    <brand>SomeBrand2</brand>
    <product>Product3</product>
    <cost>10.00</cost>
    <productType>SomeProductType</productType>
  </brand>
  <brand>
    <brand>SomeBrand2</brand>
    <product>Product4</product>
    <cost>10.00</cost>
    <productType>SomeProductType</productType>
  </brand>
</brands>
```

Comment: makes sense.  Seems customizable.  Thanks for responding